# AD DNS Server resolves old IP adress after being moved to new IP range

Tags: dns, active-directory, ip-address

I'm currently experiencing an issue with a DNS server (on Windows 2008), which was moved to a new IP range.

The IP address was changed, but somehow the server address keeps popping up as the old IP address in the DNS records, even after being changed/deleted/recreated multiple times.

Are there any suggestions how to fix this??

Comment: What was/is the TTL of the record?

Comment: The TTL is one hour...

Comment: When I change remove the old ip and resolve the new one i get the following error "A timeout Occured during validation"

Comment: Do you have a reverse DNS set up ? Is your dhcp authorized to read changes from your DNS server ? Have you tried to manually delete the record and the pointer and adding it back again ? Have you flushed DNS on the machine ?

Comment: Hey Elie, the following fixed my problem after I did it a couple of times:  manually deleted the record and the pointer and added it back again